# FB graph API: Is it possible to get other facebook user education details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two facebook users, A and B, and both of them log in via facebook API to my facebook app.

What I want to do is when logged in via facebook API as user A, to retrieve user's B education history -- is this allowed by the facebook security model?

Both user granted `user_education_history` permission to my app, both users have their education profile info publicly available, and they are friends.

Despite this, when as user A i make this graph api call:
`<fb-id-of-user-B>?fields=education`,
I receive no education details (and vice versa).

The only request then returns some education details is `me?fields=education` which successfully returns users own education details, but that is not what I need.

I use the latest facebook API version (2.8).

Comment: You need to store the user’s access tokens (extended, so that they are valid for up to two month), and then use those.

Comment: CBroe, not sure if I undestand you -- each of the requests above also includes the auth token (i.e. first I login the user via fb, retrieve token, and then attach the token to the get education details request).

Comment: The token of the user who’s data you want. A token for your user A won’t do you any good, if you want to request data for user B. Therefor, you need to use the (stored) token for user B, even if user A is currently using your app.

Comment: CBroe, thanks for clarification. I confirm than when as user A I use token of user B in facebook debug console, and call `me?fields=education`, I receive B's education details. Btw when I do this, there appears a yellow warning triangle saying "not you".

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @CBroe, will mark this community wiki.

Almost skipped this, then saw that the correct answer was provided in the comments on the original post.

When requesting data about user A's friend (user B), you'll need to use user B's authentication token in the request.

This means you'll need to have received user B's permission to access the data you're requesting, beforehand, and have stored it.